# Neither in two actions

Tags: neither-nor

I've received an email in which the sender would say:

- You haven't sent me the file neither haven't told me why I should make another technology request.

I think that it was incorrect, but, I don't know how it should be written to be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is incorrect. The word *neither* already negates the second part of the sentence, so *haven't* should not be negated again and should instead be *have*. Also, you should use *nor* instead of *neither*:

> You haven't sent me the file **nor have you** told me why I should make another technology request.

You can use *neither* to negate the first part of the sentence:

> **Neither** have you sent me the file **nor** have you told me why I should make another technology request.

When the first phrase is negated, *nor* can be used to negate the second one as well, but *neither* cannot be used for that. So the correct construction is a negative phrase with *not* or *neither* followed by a phrase negated through *nor*.

> - Neither...nor...
> - Not... nor...

In short answers you'll often see *neither*:

> - I haven't seen him.
> - **Neither** have I.

But in such sentences you could also use *nor*:

> - I haven't seen him.
> - **Nor** have I.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect. Corrected, it might be:

> You haven't sent me the file. Nor have you told me why I should...

Or perhaps

> You haven't sent me the file. You also haven't told me why I should...